# PHP to search/filter text file

Tags: php, html, shell

As the title states, How can I search a text file using PHP and variables. I want to store the user text into a variable and use that as a search parameter in the newplaces.txt file.  I know the following code does not work, but hopefully get across what I want to accomplish. I can get a match in the file, but I need help in filtering out the line to only the fields I need

```
<form method="post" action"http...">
Enter City and State <input name='place' type="text" size="10">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$f="/newplaces.txt";
$o=file($f);

$a=$_POST['place'];

$c=preg_grep("/\b$a\b/", $o);
echo implode($c, ' ');

$lat=exec("grep -i $a $f | cut -d' '' -f10 ");  //Need help with filtering the match
echo $lat;
?>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Ask a question instead

Comment: refer to this url https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+search+text+in+file

Comment: Ive updated my example code. To be more precise with my question, I guess what I'm trying to do is filter down the matched line to get only a certain field stored as $lat @manuyd

Comment: you mean line? not clear what are you trying to say

Comment: Yes, the grep will return the whole line with the match, then I want to filter it down to just the field that I want

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your shell code `"grep -i $a $f | cut -d' '' -f10 "`, you just want the 10th of the space-separated fields from the matching line. This is easily accomplished via `explode`, e. g.

```
$fields = explode(' ', $c[1]);  # $c[1] is the first matching line from the preg_grep()
$lat = $fields[10];             # $fields[10] now is the 10th field from that line
echo "The 10th field is '$lat'.\n";
```